# Entity ID was not map correctly from database during edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i did a search to Database using other field.There is only 1 item in database.

```
var product= db.products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nonID == id);
        return product;
```

the actual ID of the item for example was :112
the nonID was 888

when it was return to view with querystring id=888

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
```

the hidden field was map to nonID instead of mapping to actual ID in database that was retrived.

this caused me saving problem when ID was not found. anyone know why this was happening?
**product class**

```
 public class product
{

    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Search No")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public string nonID { get; set; }
```

**details page to edit page event**

```
<input  type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Edit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit","Product",new { id = Model.nonID})'" />


    public Product GetProductDetails(string id)
    {

        Product product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nonID == id);

        return product;
    }
```

**edit page hidden field**

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
```

**edit page querystring**

```
Product/Edit/888
```

**edit page get product details**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var product = service.GetProductDetails(id);
        ViewBag.type = new SelectList(service.GetAllProductLibrary(), "ProductTypeID", "ProductTypeName", product.type);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(product);
    }
```

when saving the edit item. entity suppose to use the ID of 112 to save .But the ID was not map to view during populating

Comment: You need to show the code in your controller method and the model

Comment: added the codes

Comment: You still have not shown the code for the `Edit` GET method (which is the most important bit)

Comment: var product= db.products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nonID == id);
        return product;//controller for edit get method also get method for details

Comment: No, The whole code! (its the signature of the method which is important) -and edit the question

Comment: hi,sorry was still updating.updated now

Comment: IMO, don't use string as the ID, use `long?`.  Then you can test `!id.HasValue` throw, otherwise send `id.Value` down the change, because ID isn't a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `Edit` method has a parameter name `id` which is added to `ModelState` when the method is called. All `HtmlHelper` methods which generate form controls use the values from `ModelState` to set the `value` attribute if they exist, so because the value of your parameter is `888`, the input generated is

```
<input .... value="888" />
```

You can solve this by adding `ModelState.Clear()` before returning the view which means the `HiddenFor()` method will use the value of your property.

A alternative solution would be to change the method to

```
public ActionResult Edit(string nonID)
```

and use `@Url.Action("Edit","Product",new { nonID = Model.nonID})` in the view. And if you wanted to output `../Product/Edit/xxx` rather than `../Product/Edit?nonID=xxx`, then you can create a specific route definition.

Comment: Thanks. i used the second approach by changing the edit parameter and the problem goes away.I always thought it was just a parameter.Yet it will affect the view population